# How to use .map() function on JSONArray in reactjs ES6

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a JSONArray returned by the server. I want to use .map() on it so that i can get key,values pairs of every object present in that array. I have written following code but i am getting error "files.map is not a function". Can anyone please help me resolve this?

```
showUploadedFiles()
  {
    const page = 1;
    const items_per_page = this.state.event.file_ids.length;
    getAllTaskFiles(this.state.event.id, page, items_per_page).then((allFiles) => {
      this.renderUploadedFiles(allFiles);
    });

  }

  renderUploadedFiles(files)
  {
    let details = null;
    details = files.map((singleFile) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#" >{singleFile.filename}</a> 
        <a href="#" >{singleFile.file_path}</a>
      </div>
      );
    });
  }
```

My JSONArray is:

```
[{"file_id": 5224879255191552, "filename": "children_walk_friends_forest_116878_3840x2160.jpg", "file_path": "/api/files/encoded_gs_file%3AdHJhY2tpbmctYXBpL3YxL2FjY291bnRzLzU2Mjk0OTk1MzQyMTMxMjAvdGFza3MvNDk5NjE4MDgzNjYxNDE0NC81MjI0ODc5MjU1MTkxNTUyL2Zha2UtemRNeklhZ1RTYl9PN3RXY2pXbkhVQT09"}, {"file_id": 4943404278480896, "filename": "banner_old.jpg", "file_path": "/api/files/encoded_gs_file%3AdHJhY2tpbmctYXBpL3YxL2FjY291bnRzLzU2Mjk0OTk1MzQyMTMxMjAvdGFza3MvNDk5NjE4MDgzNjYxNDE0NC80OTQzNDA0Mjc4NDgwODk2L2Zha2UtcmJjbDBVdVFzVmZkMjRtRUV2ME1xZz09"}]
```

Comment: Are you sure that `allFiles` or `files` are really arrays? Have you tried a `console.log()` before `.map()` ?

Comment: @Nocebo Yes, the JSONArray which i posted is actually what console.log gave me.

Comment: Now try `console.log( typeof files )` and see what it says

Comment: It says "String". @adeneo

Comment: I think i should first parse it. am i right?

Comment: yes use JSON.parse(files).map()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by other users, you have to use `JSON.parse()` to get object from your string. Here is the code snippet, storing your files in an array.

```js
const str = '[{"file_id": 5224879255191552, "filename": "children_walk_friends_forest_116878_3840x2160.jpg", "file_path": "/api/files/encoded_gs_file%3AdHJhY2tpbmctYXBpL3YxL2FjY291bnRzLzU2Mjk0OTk1MzQyMTMxMjAvdGFza3MvNDk5NjE4MDgzNjYxNDE0NC81MjI0ODc5MjU1MTkxNTUyL2Zha2UtemRNeklhZ1RTYl9PN3RXY2pXbkhVQT09"}, {"file_id": 4943404278480896, "filename": "banner_old.jpg", "file_path": "/api/files/encoded_gs_file%3AdHJhY2tpbmctYXBpL3YxL2FjY291bnRzLzU2Mjk0OTk1MzQyMTMxMjAvdGFza3MvNDk5NjE4MDgzNjYxNDE0NC80OTQzNDA0Mjc4NDgwODk2L2Zha2UtcmJjbDBVdVFzVmZkMjRtRUV2ME1xZz09"}]';

const files = JSON.parse(str);
const details = files.map((singleFile) => {
  return (
    `<div>
      <a href="#">{singleFile.filename}</a> 
      <a href="#">{singleFile.file_path}</a>
    </div>`
  );
});

console.log(details);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```